# Pulumi kubernetes ConfigGroup takes string, I only got Outputs

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, pulumi

I need to supply a Configgroup with yaml. The yaml needs to be populated with values from Pulumi Outputs. My problem is that the yaml field in the code below only take strings and I cannot figure a way to create this string from Outputs.

For example, imagine taking an Id of sorts from an Output and replacing foo.

Any ideas?

```
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";

const example = new k8s.yaml.ConfigGroup("example", {
    yaml: `
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Namespace
          metadata:
             name: foo
`,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you're needing to use an output value inside a string, you'll need to make sure the output is resolved using an `apply`.

In your case, it'd look a little bit like this:

```js
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";

const nsName = pulumi.output("foo")

nsName.apply(name => {
    const example = new k8s.yaml.ConfigGroup("example", {
        yaml: `
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Namespace
        metadata:
           name: ${name}
        `
    })
})
```

However, it's usually not desirable to create resources inside an apply like this, because it means previews aren't accurate. If you're just trying to create a namespace, it'd be highly recommend to use the kubernetes provider's namespace resource, instead of `ConfigGroup` (although I recognise you're trying to get a working example probably for something else)

You might consider using [kube2pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/kube2pulumi/) to convert whatever YAML you're installing, because once you're using the standard types, you can pass outputs to fields easily, like so:

```js
const newNs = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace("example", {
    metadata: {
        name: nsName
    }
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  I had to add an pulumi.all to collect three Outputs and then use apply.
Yeah, it is not a Namespace, actually using a Secret Store CSI driver, secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
and I had problems finding a pulumi api to use directly, thus resorting to use the yaml.ConfigGroup.

Comment: @TomHells if you start a new question for that use case, happy to help with that particular problem using native Pulumi code